# Why CreateJS code not working in firefox?

Tags: javascript, flash, audio, createjs

Have exported my flash cs6 game using createjs using "toolkit for createjs". All sounds exported to directory successfully.

Following code calls sounds

```
var manifest = [
    {src:"sounds/cutter.wav", id:"cutter"}
];

var loader = new createjs.PreloadJS(false);
loader.installPlugin(createjs.SoundJS);
loader.onComplete = handleComplete;
loader.loadManifest(manifest);

function playSound(name, loop) {
    createjs.SoundJS.play(name, createjs.SoundJS.INTERRUPT_EARLY, 0, 0, loop);
}
```

chorme and opera plays sound correctly but firefox.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Strange. The same is happening to me. I wait until the sound file is loaded before playing it. With firefox the first time i run the code the audio is playing but i can't hear any sound. If I click the play button again, the sound is reproduced correctly. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Its about quite old time, but I think there was issue in firefox and after new releases it get resolved...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying the latest code available at http://www.soundjs.com.  You'll also find helpful tutorials and examples that work in firefox.  It doesn't offer direct toolkit support, but it can help you understand what the exported code is doing and how to alter it.

My best guess without seeing the code in context is you are trying to call play without waiting for load to complete.  This creates a race condition, where sometimes if the sound is cached it will work, and other times it will fail.

It's also possible that it has something to do with the wav encoding.  With mp3s we've found you mostly need to stick to default encoding to ensure browsers can actually play the audio.  You might also want to consider using mp3 and ogg files for the broadest [audio support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_Audio).

Hope that helps.